# Isn’t there an “132” pattern in [3,5,0,3,4]?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

Problem:Given a sequence of n integers a1, a2, ..., an, a 132 pattern is a subsequence ai, aj, ak such that i < j < k and ai < ak < aj. Design an algorithm that takes a list of n numbers as input and checks whether there is a 132 pattern in the list.

Note: n will be less than 15,000.

Example 1:

Input: [1, 2, 3, 4]

Output: False

Explanation: There is no 132 pattern in the sequence.
Example 2:

Input: [3, 1, 4, 2]

Output: True

Explanation: There is a 132 pattern in the sequence: [1, 4, 2].

Example 3:
Input: [-1, 3, 2, 0]

Output: True

Explanation: There are three 132 patterns in the sequence: [-1, 3, 2], [-1, 3, 0] and [-1, 2, 0].

My code:

```
class Solution456{
public boolean find132pattern(int[] nums) {
    int i=0,j=i+1,k=j+1;
    if(nums.length<3){
        return false;
    }
    while(i<nums.length-2){
        if(nums[i]<nums[j] && nums[j]>nums[k] && nums[i] < nums[k] && nums[k] < nums[j]){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            i++;
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }

    return false;

}
}
```

Which passes all the above mentioned testcases. But [image]
Cannot pass this test case. I don't know why. For test case int [] nums={3,5,0,3,4}; it cannot pass. Is it  fall in 132 pattern? Why the Expected output will be **true**?

Can anyone explain me what is the bug in my code or logic?

Comment: `0, 1, -4` is not a 132 sequence, since first value is not lower than last value. You are testing `nums[i] < nums[j] && nums[j] > nums[k]` but you're supposed to be testing `nums[i] < nums[k] && nums[k] < nums[j]`

Comment: Are you checking only adjacent cells? Will your program find [1, 3, 2] in [5, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, -1]?

Comment: not really related to Java, more a problem of interpretation/mathematics/logic. `a < c < b` is not the same as `(a < b) and (b > c)`

Comment: @Andreas It cannot pass [3,5,0,3,4] test case. But definitely your logic work well for other test cases.

Comment: @Encipher So debug your code and figure out why it can't see the `3,5,4` solution. Remember, `i`, `j`, and `k` don't have to refer to *adjacent* values, so here the solution is found for `i = 0, j = 1, k = 4`, where the check for `a[i] < a[k] < a[j]`, i.e. `3 < 4 < 5`, is true.

Answer (score 2):

From the definition of the ***132 pattern*** it's obvious that you need to manage 3 indexes `i`, `j` and `k` in order to loop through all the possible triples of the array items that satisfy the condition `i < j < k`.
So:
`i` can take every value from `0` up to the `length of the array - 2` (excluded)
`j` can take every value from `i + 1` up to the `length of the array - 1` (excluded)
`k` can take every value from `j + 1` up to the `length of the array` (excluded)
This means that you need a 3 level deep `for` loop. 
You tried to solve the problem with a single loop and I don't think that this is possible .
 So this is my solution:

```
public static boolean find132pattern(int[] nums) {
    if(nums.length < 3)
        return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 2; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length - 1; j++) {
            for (int k = j + 1; k < nums.length; k++) {
                if(nums[i] < nums[k] && nums[k] < nums[j]){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I tested for these cases:

```
int[] array1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
System.out.println(find132pattern(array1));
```

prints `false`

```
int[] array2 = {3, 1, 4, 2};
System.out.println(find132pattern(array2));
```

prints `true`

```
int[] array3 = {-1, 3, 2, 0};
System.out.println(find132pattern(array3));
```

prints `true`

```
int[] array4 = {3, 5, 0, 3, 4};
System.out.println(find132pattern(array4));
```

prints `true`

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I know if I take three for loops then it is more convenient approach. But I want to implement it by taking one while loop and using i,j,k as counter. Can I implement it with my approach? Also is there any other way besides brute force method?

Comment: @Encipher But in your logic, `i`, `j`, and `k` are always 1 apart, and that isn't correct.

Comment: @Andreas The for loop you write doing the same thing.

Comment: @Encipher Huh? I haven't written any `for` loop. I'm not the poster of this answer. I was just pointing out to you, that your code always increment all 3 at the same time, so you check `i=0,j=1,k=2`, then `i=1,j=2,k=3`, then `i=2,j=3,k=4`, and stops, i.e. 3 checks with values 1 apart, but the code in this answer checks `i=0,j=1,k=2`, then `i=0,j=1,k=3`, then `i=0,j=1,k=4`, then `i=0,j=2,k=3`, then `i=0,j=2,k=4`, then `i=0,j=3,k=4`, then `i=1,j=2,k=3`, then `i=1,j=2,k=4`, then `i=1,j=3,k=4`, then `i=2,j=3,k=4`, i.e. 10 checks.

Comment: @Encipher *I want to implement it by taking one while loop* this is not possible because for each of the n-2 values of i you must check n-2 values of j and for each of the n-2 values of j you must check n-2 values of k. *is there any other way besides brute force method?* no there isn't.  Every possible triple with the condition i<j<k must be checked and this stops only if the 132 condition is met or all the triples all checked. *The for loop you write doing the same thing* no it does not. Your loop starts with i=0, j=1, k=2 and continues by checking only adjacent triples.

Answer (score 1):

A [subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) doesn't have to be contiguous. The `3, 5, 4` in `3, 5, 0, 3, 4` is a valid 132 pattern. You're only checking contiguous subsequences.